# Seria possivel um contador de sequencia alfabetica?

Tags: array, string, contador, inteiros

Estou fazendo um codigo no pascal onde um de meus arrays tem valores do alfabeto (de A a Z) para um projeto pessoal do tipo *Perguntas e Respostas/ Significados de A a Z*:

```
aux[1]:= 'a';
aux[2]:= 'b';
aux[3]:= 'c';
...
aux[24]:= 'x';
aux[25]:= 'y';
aux[26]:= 'z';
```

Foi rapido, mas por um instante achei chato ter que digita-los, então eu pensei:

"*Eu sei que texto é texto e número é número. Mas será que o programa (Pascal ou qualquer outro) poderia reconhecer o alfabeto como uma especie de sequencia textual ou variável alfabetica ?*"

Algo do tipo:

```
Alfa:Array [ a..z] of 'variavel alfabetica'
```

Talvez alguns programas pudessem incluir alguma especie de biblioteca ou função, não sei, e eu poderia usar de um contador com sequencia *Alfabetica* ao invés de *númerico*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sim**, é possível. Assumindo 26 letras no alfabeto, você pode criar um sistema de base-26 para expressar valores numéricos como texto. Este formato é chamado *hexavigesimal bijetivo*.

Neste formato, o valor **65535** é expresso via *string* **CRXO**.

Isto feito, você pode agora implementar um *array* onde as chaves são valores hexavigesimais ao invés de numéricos.

Um exemplo de implementação, em javascript, segue abaixo:

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app.controller('SampleController', function($scope, $http) {

  function bijectiveBase26(value) {

    var sequence = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var length = sequence.length;

    if (value <= 0) return value;
    if (value <= length) return sequence[value - 1];


    var index = (value % length) || length;
    var result = [sequence[index - 1]];

    while ((value = Math.floor((value - 1) / length)) > 0) {
      index = (value % length) || length;
      result.push(sequence[index - 1]);
    }
    return result.reverse().join("");
  }

  $scope.b2Array = {};

  
  //Populando o array com chaves hexavigesimais
  for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    $scope.b2Array[bijectiveBase26(2000 + i)] = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
  }

  $scope.valor = 65535;

  $scope.$watch("valor",
    function(newValue) {
      $scope.codigo = bijectiveBase26(newValue);
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sampleApp">

  <div ng-controller="SampleController">

    Valor:
    <input type='text' ng-model='valor' />
    <br/>Código: {{codigo}}
    <br/>
    <br/>Array: 
    <br/>{{b2Array | json}}


  </div>
</div>
```